# How to connect other application database from my own Application in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, root

I trying to write a code in Android to connect to other application database from my own application but i am not able to connect it , i am getting **SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException**.

**MyCode:**

```
package com.example.testdbconnection;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

String file_url = "/data/data/com.android.keychain/databases/"; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 try
 {

    SQLiteDatabase sdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(file_url, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    if(sdb==null)
    {

        Log.d("Database not Connected", "....");

    }
    else
    {

        Log.d("Database Connected", "....");

    }   

 }  
 catch(SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException e)
 {

     Log.d("Database not Connected", "....");

 }  
}}
```

I think if i can able to rooted my device then can it be possible? But this is also not good to make rooted device because then it will work only in my device then it won't work in other devices.

Please suggest me some solution , how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it. What you want to use in this case is a content provider (even if I don't know if the other apps provide you a content provider). You can see example of how to use it [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Comment: Yes i agreed , so then if i will use Content Provider then can i put the DB in SDCARD and i will try to access from Content Provider. Can it be possible?

Comment: I don't know your use case, but in general a content provider can provide an access interface for data whose owner is an other app

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** access other application's private data directories (unless the device was rooted and your app had superuser permissions).